# iOS How to find multiple strings between 2 strings in a huge string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring, substring

I have a jumbled up `NSString` let's say

```
dsadasdasd"my_id": "qwerr"dcdscsdcds"my_id": "oytuj"adasddasddsddaS"my_id": "sjghjgjg"ddsfsdfsdf
```

How can I find every instance of string between the

```
"my_id": "
```

and the next

```
"
```

So here, I want the result to be an `NSArray` of:

```
qwerr
oytuj
sjghjgjg
```

I am looking for hints, regex or any other solutions would be good. I have tried many ways of using `NSRange` and `substringWithRange` combinations but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Is `"my_id": "` constant? (i.e. always the same string with same length with that space in the middle etc)

Comment: @Arc676 yes, it will always stay like that with same length and space between the colon and doublequote

Comment: Then you do not need a regex if you can just split with a known substring.

Comment: @stribizhev but is there a way to grab multiple instances of those? instead of having to loop through it again and again till finish?

Comment: Where do you get that string? I'm wondering if in fact, it's not from a JSON or a NSDictionary... And if that's the case, that's clearly not the good way to do it.

Comment: @Larme n case you are curious, I am working on something to recover huge json files which are highly corrupted. the original string is a combination of a lot of "my_id" and the only way to recover the most is by getting all the "my_id" and then recreating the json by fetching information about those ids. One of the solutions below by stribizhev worked perfectly after adapting it to my corrupted json file strings.

Comment: @PranoyC: Ok, it's because it's corrupted. Eitherwise, I would have recommend you to parse it, because there are a lot of people on SO who transform their JSON into string and then ask how to retrieve values, where it shouldn't be transformed to string at first.

Comment: @Larme yeah I convert json to nsdictionary for parsing usually. but this one is not possible to as it's corrupt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have overlooked the closing quote requirement. Well, in this case, the code with or without regex will be similar in length.

Here is a regex suggestion that basically extracts all substrings after `"my_id": "` and up to the next `"` or the end of string:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *pattern = @"\"my_id\": \"([^\"]+)";
NSString *string = @"dsadasdasd\"my_id\": \"qwerr\"dcdscsdcds\"my_id\": \"oytuj\"adasddasddsddaS\"my_id\": \"sjghjgjg\"ddsfsdfsdf";
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:range];
for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches) {
    NSRange group1 = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"group1: %@", [string substringWithRange:group1]);
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/OaabrC)

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly! in case you are curious, I am working on something to recover huge json files. the original string is a combination of a lot of "my_id" and the only way to recover the most is by getting all the "my_id" and then recreating the json by fetching information about those ids. This solution works perfectly after adapting it to my json file strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a regex like this:

```
"my_id": "\K[^"]+
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/dR0xE5/1)

Or this:

```
(?<="my_id": ")[^"]+
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you, one of the solutions above worked perfectly so I accepted that! Appreciate your answers too!

Answer (score 0):

Your title says "huge" string. I will assume you don't know how many occurrences there will be.

I would use `NSMutableString` and `NSRange`. See the [`NSMutableString` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/index.html), [`NSString` doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html), and [`NSRange` doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSRange).

**Disclaimer:** this code is untested and doesn't use regexes because this is an alternative method and regexes might not be the right solution for this (supported by another commenter).

```
NSMutableString *string = //mutable copy of however you get the "jumbled" string
//To get the mutable copy use [string mutableCopy]
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array]; //new array
NSRange *range = [string rangeOfString:@"\"my_id\": \""]; //find the my_id part
while (range.location != -1){ //if not found, location is -1
    //delete the irrelevant parts of the string (you should keep a copy of the original)
    //the length of the my_id part is 10
    [string deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, range.location - 1 + 10)];
    NSRange *end = [string rangeOfString:@"\""]; //find the next " char
    NSString *str = [string substringToIndex:end.location]; //get the relevant part
    [array addObject:str]; //save it
    [string deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, end.location)];
    range = [string rangeOfString:@"\"my_id\": \""];
}
```

Comment: thank you, one of the solutions above worked perfectly so I accepted that! Your solution might work but the above one was shorter.